# Fib2 function without recursion in Python

Tags: python, iteration, func

I need help for defining the fibanocci 2 function. The fibanocci 2 function is decribed as :
fib2(n) = {0 if  n <= 0, 1 if  n = 1, 2 if  n = 2, ( fib2( n - 1) * fib2( n - 2)) - fib2( n - 3) else}

We need to define this function iterative.
I tried my best but i couldn't write a working code.

```
def fib2(n: int) -> int:
    if n <= 0:
        return 0
    elif n == 1:
        return 1
    elif n == 2:
        return 2
    else:
        n = ((n - 1) * (n - 2) - (n - 3)
    return n
a = fib2(7)
print (a)
assert (fib2(7) == 37)
```

the output from this fib2 function is 26 but it should be 37.
Thank you in advance

Comment: This is the beggining of a recurrsive function you are showing us. What have you tried yet for the iterative version ?

Comment: what is the fibonacci 2 function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the iterative version you have to use a for loop.
And just add the 3 previous numbers to get the next one.

Here is a piece of code:

```
def fib3(n):
    a = 0
    b = 1
    c = 0
    for n in range(n):
        newc = a+b+c
        a = b
        b = c
        c = newc
    return newc

print(fib3(7))
assert (fib3(7) == 37)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not change the value of a parameter.
Please try to return directly :
Return ((fb2(n-1)×fb2(n-2))-fb2(n-3))
So it will work as a recursive function.

Comment: this is recurive, and not what the OP is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
def fibo(n):
    current = 0
    previous_1 = 1
    previous_2 = 0
    
    for i in range(1,n):
        current = previous_1 + previous_2
        previous_2 = previous_1
        previous_1 = current
    return current
```

To do it iteratively, the best way is to write it on paper to understand how it works.

Mathematically fibo is `Fn = Fn-1 + Fn-2` . Therefore, you can create variables called `previous_1` and `previous_2` which represents the elements of `Fn` and you simply update them on each run.

`Fn` is `current`